# Grammatical Reasoning?

Tags: grammar

This is clearly an ungrammatical sentence:
"Freddy would like to see the home-opener, but tickets are unable to be purchased by him."

An obvious correction would be: "Freddy would like to see the home-opener, but is unable to purchase the tickets."

But how does one *describe* the grammatical problem in the original sentence?
That tickets do not possess the property of "ability"?
But then: "Tickets enabled Freddy to enter the gate."

I apologize for the inartfulness of how I pose this question, and I hope someone is able to get past that and offer clarification.
Thank you.

Comment: The problem is not grammatical but semantic: the sentence is structured perfectly grammatically, but its wording generates an unintended or ambiguous meaning.

Comment: Thanks for making me search for a definition of 'home-opener'. I was getting quite flummoxed as to why Freddy would need a ticket to watch a home being opened. ;)

Comment: "tickets are unable to be purchased by [Freddy] " tells me (in a roundabout way) that there is a reason that Freddy cannot purchase tickets but someone else might be able to.

Comment: It's not "wrong", it's just not "right".

Answer (score 1):

The verbal construction *be able to* requires a person as its "agent"-subject in the context of your example. The verb *enable* lacks this requirement and can take both animate and inanimate subjects. If you say *[thing] is able to...*, that sounds like a metaphor, a (slight) case of personification. That is possible in certain situations, but not in a basic example such as this.

You could say that, in the case of *enable*, the subject is not that which becomes able, but the object:

> Tickets enabled **Freddy** to enter

The object of *enable* needs to be a person in this context. The subject, however, does not, because it does not become "able" itself.

You may be interested in exploring the topic of *[semantic roles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation)*.

Comment: Not true at all. AHDEL has in a usage note: 'The new submarine is able to dive twice as fast as the older model. Some people think it should be avoided when the subject does not have an ability ...'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Again, I have no idea what that abbreviation means, but you seem to be giving the exact same argument there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that the submarine is envisaged as having agency in that sentence, although it isn't animate. It wouldn't do in a sentence such as *the submarine was able to be bought*, for example.

Comment: @Araucaria: Right, it is easier to personify "vehicles" a little, things that seem to have a purpose.

Comment: @Araucaria While your 'the submarine is envisaged as having agency in that sentence' doubtless contains some truth, the fact that AHDEL says 'Some people think it should be avoided when the subject does not have an ability' shows that their research must show that 'Some people think it may be used even in cases when the subject does not have an ability'. As I say, I don't like '... any fire door is unable to be opened in an emergency ...', used by a UK Government Department, but that doesn't mean I can go beyond the 'some people think that ...' position that AHDEL says exists.

Comment: Thank you both for your thoughtful remarks. (AHDEL = American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with attempting to use a passive construction with '[un]able to'.

> The door is [un]able to open. [internet examples]

doesn't sound too bad. But

> ... any fire door is unable to be opened in an emergency ...

sounds off to my ears also.

However, this second quote is from swindon.gov.uk, so one assumes it is a legal usage.

I'll add the usage note from [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/able):

> Usage Note: The construction able to takes an infinitive to show the
>   subject's ability to accomplish an action: We were able to get a grant
>   for the project. The new submarine is able to dive twice as fast as
>   the older model. Some people think it should be avoided when the
>   subject does not have an ability, as in sentences with passive
>   constructions involving forms of the verb be: The problem was able to
>   be solved by using a new lab technique. The reasoning here is that
>   since the problem has no ability to accomplish an action, it is not
>   able to do anything, and therefore able to should not be used.
>   Presumably this ban would apply to similar words like capable and to
>   negative words like unable and incapable. In such cases one can
>   usually avoid the problem by using can or could: The problem could be
>   solved.... Keep in mind, however, that passives with get ascribe a
>   more active role to their subjects, and here one can use able to: He
>   was able to get accepted by a top law school.

There should be the same taboo against using 'capable of' (+ being + infinitive) with a subject where an attribution of capability is nonsensical, but there are nearly 700 000 Google hits for "is capable of being solved". English usage often broadens metonymically; doubtless there are still people objecting stridently to 'I boiled a kettle'.

Comment: Both examples sound off to me. But I suppose anything is possible in informal Internet usage...

Comment: I've given an example from AHDEL.

Comment: I don't know what that is, but I would not consider your examples "proper", the kind of English the OP is looking for.

Comment: FWIW, the second one actually sounds better to me than the first.

Comment: The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language. Rather more clout than individuals. And I don't find their 'The new submarine is able to dive twice as fast as the older model' at all unacceptable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd pretty much reckon that any time a usage dictionary has to say *some people reckon you shouldn't* then you can give a cast iron guarantee that what follows is often, if not always, grammatical - otherwise there would be no examples for them to rail against! ;)

Comment: By the way, I think the passive thing is not quite a complete explanation. It's just that the subject of a passive sentence is almost never an agent, which is why such a construction doesn't work; it doesn't really make sense to speak of ability unless it is of an agent that has this ability. But *be able* doesn't work in other contexts that rule out any agency of the subject: **he was able to fail, no matter how hard he tried* (only works ironically); **the memory was able to recede quickly* (doesn't work because a memory is not personifiable such that it can deliberately recede).

Comment: Again, I thank you all very much for your very thoughtful comments.